# how to set buffer size manually in vitamio player android? Because my .ts file size 12MB but it takes only 4MB per segment. How to increase?

Tags: java, android, vitamio, android-developer-api

```
{
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        String url = i.getStringExtra("movieUrl");
        urlArray = url.trim().split(",");
        urlLength = urlArray.length;
        tempString = urlArray[loop].toString();
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(tempString);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        // Show progressbar
        progressDialog.show();
    }
```

Because my .ts file size 12MB but it takes only 4MB per segment. How to increase?

Comment: have you tried mVideoView.setBufferSize( int size) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set buffer size by accessing MediaPlayer object.

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //mp.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_LOW);
        //mp.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
        mp.setBufferSize(1024*1024*4);//4MB buffer size
    }
});
```

You can check the [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783877/how-to-set-buffer-size-manually-in-vitamio-player-android-because-my-ts-file-s) for more info.

```
/**
   * The buffer to fill before playback, default is 1024*1024 Byte 
   *
   * @param bufSize buffer size in Byte
   */
  public native void setBufferSize(long bufSize);
```

You can use the following buffer size calculator. It gives you how many seconds you should set for the buffer size. ([source](http://www.betriebsraum.de/blog/2007/02/27/flash-video-tip-1-calculating-an-optimal-buffer-size/)) And then you can calculate your buffer size in bytes.

```
// buffer padding in sec.
// should be at least twice as long as the keyframe interval and fps, e.g.:
// keyframe interval of 30 at 30fps --> min. 2 sec.
public static int BUFFER_PADDING = 3;

// videoLength in sec., videoBitrate and bandwidth in kBits/Sec
public static int calculate(int videoLength, int videoBitrate, int bandwidth) {
    int bufferTime;
    if (videoBitrate > bandwidth) {
        bufferTime = (int) Math.ceil(videoLength - videoLength / (videoBitrate / bandwidth));
    } else {
        bufferTime = 0;
    }
    bufferTime += BUFFER_PADDING;

    return bufferTime;
}
```